# Transfer Whatsapp from Android to Windows phone

Tags: whatsapp, backup

I'm trying to transfer whatsapp data from my android phone to windows. I copied the 'whatsapp' folder from android storage to the root folder of windows and then installed whatsapp in windows and opened it. It asked me if i wanted to restore from the backup that it has detected. However, the problem is that even after i restore, it said '7 messages have been restored'. I have 1000's of texts obviously. But only the unread messages have been restored. Am i missing out anything here? Or is it literally impossible?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot restore chat history from any other phone type to Windows Phone, or from Windows Phone to another phone type. Read more at WhatsApp Official Website: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/28060005

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible you cannot copy app data from one platform to another(Its like pouring water into a wine glass and calling it wine).

When Whatsapp asked you about the backup it was restored from their servers not from the local app data.
You can manually backup your messages from the Android Whatsapp settings and then later restore it on your windows mobile(Im doubtful whether Whatsapp can backup everything but give it a go and let us know)